# Laravel check if id exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've two columns in contents tables
 1. id
 2. content

now this is what i'm trying to do

```
Route::post('save', function()
{
    $editor_content=Input::get('editor_content');
    $rules = array('editor_content' => 'required');
    $validator= Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if($validator->passes())
    {
        //1. check if id is  submitted?
        //2. if id exists update content table 
        //3. else insert new content
            //create new instance
            $content= new Content;
            // insert the content to content column
            $content->content = $editor_content;
            //save the content
            $content->save();
            // check if content has id
            $id=$content->id;

         return Response::json(array('success' => 'sucessfully saved', 'id' => $id));    
        }
    if($validator->fails())
    {
       return $validator->messages() ; 
    }

    });
```

i wanted to check if id has been already submit or checked i'm processing the request via ajax, and if id exists i wanted update the content column and if it doesn't i wanted to create new instance  how do i do it ?

Comment: use Content::firstOrCreate($data); it will do the same

Comment: I believe you will need to pass in the id if you want to update that record, other way there is no way for you to know which column needs updating because the content can change.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line:

```
$content= new Content;
```

with:

```
$content = Content::firstOrCreate(array('id' => $editor_content['id'])); //this will check for the id in contents table and create a new record if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: undefined variable even if i place $id before?

Comment: Yep, the edited version should work, sorry about the typo, it suppose to be an array.

Comment: i'm still getting undefined variable even with array

Comment: Which is the undefined variable by the way? the $id? that's really just an example on how you would get the id of the record. In your case it should be $editor_content['id']